# Android Memory Maps

Tags: android, memory-management

Hello I have a question to the Android memory management. When I read the memory maps of a process via adb like this:

```
cat /proc/12345/maps
```

I get this result:

```
...
b76df000-b76e7000 rw-p 00187000 08:06 870        /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
b76e7000-b76e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76e8000-b76e9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:linker_alloc]
b76e9000-b76ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:linker_alloc]
b76ea000-b76eb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:linker_alloc]
b76eb000-b76ec000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76ec000-b76ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76ee000-b7704000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 295        /system/bin/linker
b7704000-b7705000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7705000-b7706000 r--p 00016000 08:06 295        /system/bin/linker
b7706000-b7707000 rw-p 00017000 08:06 295        /system/bin/linker
b7707000-b7708000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7708000-b770c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 229        /system/bin/app_process32
b770c000-b770d000 r--p 00003000 08:06 229        /system/bin/app_process32
b770d000-b770e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf15a000-bf15a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf15a000-bf959000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

I can't see a line for the heap. Isn't the heap space always present and should be listet in the memory maps of a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you see any entries like this?

12c00000-12e07000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 25425                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
12e07000-12e97000 rw-p 00207000 00:04 25425                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
12e97000-1ec00000 ---p 00297000 00:04 25425                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)

Dalvik/Art allocate heap through ashmem. Obviously you wouldn't see these in a native process.

Comment: Yes I see them. Thanks for your advice. I'm new in this domain and I wasn't aware of this circumstance. I searched only for heap.